# MongoDB Update field data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reactjs, express, mongodb-query

How can i used db.findAndUpdate table user and change my balance from previous amount to newer?
i have try to get balance and the result it show nothing, now i'm confuse to write in findAndUpdate. here's my code:

api:

```
app.post('/api/account/transfer', (req, res, next) => {
    const { body } = req;
    const {
      sender,
      receiver,
      amount,
      user,
      balance,
    } = body;


    if (!sender) {
      return res.send({
        success: false,
        message: 'Error: Sender cannot be blank!'
      });
    }
    if (!receiver) {
      return res.send({
        success: false,
        message: 'Error: Receiver cannot be blank!'
      });
    }
    if (!amount) {
      return res.send({
        success: false,
        message: 'Error: Fill Amount!'
      });
    } else if(balance < amount || balance == 0) {
      return res.send({
        success: false,
        message: 'Insufficient funds!'
      });
    }

    //save the new transaction
    const newTransaction = new Transaction();

    newTransaction.sender = sender;
    newTransaction.receiver = receiver;
    newTransaction.amount = amount;

    newTransaction.save( (err, transaction) => {
      if(err) {
        return res.send({
          success: false,
          message: 'Error: Server error.'
        });
      }else{
        return res.send({
          success: true,
          message: 'Transfer Success!'
        });
      }
    });

    //update user balance
    User.findOneAndUpdate({
    });
```

and here's the screenshoot:
[image: transaction]

so what i want is, if i'm as a receiver my balance will be increase.

Comment: findOneAndUpdate never returns the balance to you, but you can instruct mongo to perform the calulation by its this own by using [$inc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/#behavior). Something along the lines of: `User.findOneAndUpdate({_id:sender}, { $inc: { balance: newTransaction.amount }});`. Just an educated guess, not tested.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, the findOneAndUpdate operation does not wait for save operation to complete.

```
app.post('/api/account/transfer', (req, res, next) => {
    const {
        body
    } = req;

    const fields = ['sender', 'receiver', 'amount', 'balance'];
    fields.forEach((field) => {
        if (!body[field]) {
            return res.send({
                success: false,
                message: 'Error: ' + field + ' cannot be blank!'
            });
        }
    })
    if (body.balance < body.amount || body.balance == 0) {
        return res.send({
            success: false,
            message: 'Insufficient funds!'
        });
    }

    //save the new transaction
    let newTransaction = new Transaction();
    // newTransaction = Object.assign(newTransaction, body); // If you want to copy all params from body to newTransaction 
    newTransaction.sender = body.sender;
    newTransaction.receiver = body.receiver;
    newTransaction.amount = body.amount;

    newTransaction.save((err, transaction) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.send({
                success: false,
                message: 'Error: Server error.'
            });
        } else {
            //update user balance
            User.findOneAndUpdate({
                /*query*/
            }, {
                /*body*/
            }, (err, data) => {
                if (err)
                    return res.send({
                        success: false,
                        message: 'Error: Server error.'
                    });
                return res.send({
                    success: true,
                    message: 'Transfer Success!'
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```